# ListBoxItem with Runs does not allow mouse selection on text

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, textblock, listboxitem

I'm creating a `ListBox` with items that have a portion of the text highlighted.  This would normally be a search term, but for this simple example I'm just using "NEW".  The highlighting works (lifted from a tutorial), but when mouse is over the text portion of the `ListBoxItem` it does not get the blue highlight and cannot be selected.  Clicking in the white space to the right of the text does allow it to be selected.  How can I fix the `Run`s so that they accept the mouse hover and selection?

Sample VS solution utilizing WPF:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8bhogp3k75rkoj/RunHoverTest.zip?dl=0
Left side of window is normal `ListBox`, right side is with highlighting applied in `OnLoaded` event.

I looked into adding a mouse hover event to the `Run` but got stuck on how to pass it down to the `TextBlock`.  Any suggestion to do the highlighting differently to make it work is also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: A run is part of a textblock so not a great choice if you wanted mouseover on a particular part. I put together a search sample highlit text some time back. Before I go and dig it out, could you please ensure all your requirements are clearly defined in your question? They are not at the moment. Posting a link to a zip is a bad idea btw. If you would download some random zip off the web then you should think again. I'm guessing your question has close votes because you have no code in it. But it could also be because it does not clearly define requirements.

Comment: It's too much code to post for someone to replicate in their own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an explicit `DataTemplate` in the view:

```
<ListBox Name="HighlightedListBox" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllStates}"
    Loaded="ListBox_OnLoaded">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This should make the items selectable.